# Javascript csom to access Page Properties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have some wiki pages in SharePoint 2013 Onpremise "Site Pages" Library. I have created a column "Priority" in the library . I want to access the Page Property from Client Side. I know this is possible from Server side by the following code:

```
SPContext.Current.ListItem["FieldName"]
```

But i want to access the Page properties from Client Side , is it possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [SPContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.current(v=office.15).aspx) gets the context of the current HTTP request and `SPContext.Current.ListItem` returns the current List Item I assume you to need a similar functionality in JSOM.

In SharePoint the structure `_spPageContextInfo` is available on every page on the client-side that could be considered to some extent as analogue to  [SPContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.current(v=office.15).aspx). In particular, the following properties are exposed to identify the current List Item:

- `pageListId` - gets the current List Unique Id
- `pageItemId` - gets the current List Item Id

### How to retrieve current List Item using JSOM

The following function demonstrates how to retrieve current List Item:

```
function getCurrentListItem(success, error)
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 
   var currentList = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId); 
   var currentListItem = currentList.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);
   context.load(currentListItem);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
        success(currentListItem);
     }, 
     error
   );
}
```

Usage

```
getCurrentListItem(
   function(listItem) {
       var priority = listItem.get_item('Priority'); 
       console.log(priority);
   },
   function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());    
   }
);
```

Comment: I am not able to do this when page is not checked out
is there a way where I can add .CheckOut() and do this?

Comment: I am trying listItem.set_item()
which works when page is checked out